# why does a variation in the if statement of this bitwise operation cause an error?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am writing a function to print bits but i ran into a problem. The two for loops seem identical to me but for some reason the one that is commented out does not print the right bits.

```
int main()
{
unsigned int bits = 0x570FA1; 
unsigned int mask = 0x800000;

printBits(bits, 24, mask);

  return 0;
}
void printBits(unsigned int bit, int numbOfBits, unsigned int& mask){


   for (int i = 1; i <= numbOfBits; i++){
       if ((mask & bit) == 0 ){
            cout << "0";
       }
       else {

       cout <<"1";
       }
       mask = mask >> 1;
       if ( i %4 == 0 ){
        cout << " ";
       }
   }

/*   for(int i= 1 ; i <= numbOfBits ; i++ ){
         if ((mask & bit) ==1){
            cout << "1";
         }
         else{
            cout << "0";

         }
      mask = mask >> 1;
      if(i% 4 ==0){
         cout << " ";
      }
   }*/
}
```

Comment: Given the initial value of `mask`, `mask & bit` is either `mask` or `0`. Most of the time, `mask` isn't 1.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger and inspecting the argument to the `if` statement.

Comment: Replace `==1` with `==mask` or `!=0` .

Comment: Why are you passing `mask` by reference?

Comment: @wazeeer: Well, the first question for you would be: what made you expect these two versions to work equivalently? Why do you say that "they look identical to you", while they are definitely not identical?

Comment: You need to explain what you think are "the right bits". By definition we cannot magically divine that from a piece of code that, by your own admission, _does not produce them_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason's very simple: the mask value might start at something like 128, then be right-shifted to 64, 32, etc..  So, in...

```
if ((mask & bit) == 0 ){
```

...if the masked bit is set the bitwise AND will return the mask bit, and everything works as hoped.  But in...

```
if ((mask & bit) ==1){
```

The bitwise AND returns the mask bit which may be greater than 1: for example `128 != 1`, and even though the bit you're testing is set you mistakenly think it's off.  The only time it will happen to work is when `mask` has finally been right-shifted to `1`.